# Instruction expected to be numbered

Tags: llvm

I have a problem with the following LLVM code:

```
    %0 = load i64* %u
    %1 = load i64* %l
    %2 = icmp sgt i64 %1, %1
    br i1 %2, label %L1, label %L2
L2:
    ret void
    br label %L1
L1:

    %3 = load i64* %l
    %4 = sub i64 %3, 1
    store i64 %4, i64* %i
```

When running `llc`, I get the following error:

```
error: instruction expected to be numbered '%4'
%3 = load i64* %l
```

But I don't understand why it should be `%4` after `%2`. There are no instruction returning a result between the `%2` and `%4`.

I need to understand this because I am writing an LLVM code generator.

So why is it an error to use `%3` here?

Comment: In lieu of br label %L1, could you switch this to "unreachable"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Basic blocks share the same numbering as instructions. Because `ret` is a terminator, you have an unnamed (and unreachable) basic block starting right after it, so your code is equivalent to:

```
...
L2:
  ret void
%3:
  br label %L1
L1:
...
```

And that's why it expects the next unnamed thing to be `%4`.